# Por qué me sale este error al intentar compilar mi app? Build file: build.gradle' line: 25

Tags: android, android-studio

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Project with path ':app' could not be found in project ':cloud_firestore'.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 884ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Y cuál es el gradle que tienes definido para tu app? [edit] y añadir la info relevante, **como texto**

Comment: Tengo la versión de gradle 7.3.3

Comment: Por favor, ¿podrías enseñar el código?

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que no existe un módulo definido en tu proyecto `cloud_firestore`:

> Project with path ':app' could not be found in project
> ':cloud_firestore'.

En este caso `:app` se refiere a el proyecto principal, esto debe ser definido en el archivo `settings.gradle` de tu proyecto.

Este es un ejemplo de lo que debe tener definido tu archivo, incluso cuando haces uso de una biblioteca (como ejemplo una llamada "Library1") debes definirla también:

```
include ':app'
include ':Library1'
```

---

**Asegura que tienes el archivo `settings.gradle` en la raiz de tu proyecto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**y que este contiene al menos lo siguiente**:

```
include ':app'
```